# Como usar o comando 'for' para solucionar o mesmo problema?

Tags: python, for, while

No caso, o objetivo do programa era fazer uma meia pirâmide, como tantos andares que o usuário quisesse construir, entretanto, queria usar o comando 'for', para cumprir esse objetivo.

```
quant = int(input('Quantos andares você quer que tenha a meia pirâmide? '))
while quant >= 1:
  print('* ' * quant, end ='')
  print('')
  quant -= 1

>>> Quantos andares você quer que tenha a meia pirâmide? 4
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `for` existe para percorrer coleções de dados, então você tem que gerar uma coleção de números começando em quantidade, indo até 0, com o passo de cada variação do número sendo negativo para ir decrementando o valor. Isso é feito com a função [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Aproveitei para simplificar o código. Mas não trate erro se a pessoa não digitar um valor numérico, o que causaria a quebra da aplicação.

Dá até para fazer com uma linha, mas eu não gosto, não aumenta a legibilidade, só deixa mais curto, que são coisas diferentes.

```
quant = int(input('Quantos andares você quer que tenha a meia pirâmide? '))
print('')
for n in range(quant, 0, -1):
    print('* ' * n)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/dheOK3). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vatzprwc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/For2.py).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar outra variavel para fazer a vez da base.

```
quant = int(input('Quantos andares você quer que tenha a meia pirâmide? '))
p = quant

for x in range(quant):
  print('* ' * p, end ='')
  print('')
  p -= 1
```

A piramide em pé é mais simples

```
quant = int(input('Quantos andares você quer que tenha a meia pirâmide? '))

for x in range(quant):
  print('* ' * x, end ='')
  print('')
```